# "Leave the door open" vs "let the door open"

Tags: word-usage, word-difference, let

Can I mean "May I leave the door open?" by asking "May I let the door open?" in any context? I know that there is, of course, a difference in meaning in both of the sentences, but I'm just wondering if I can ask "Should I let the door open?" to mean "Should I let the door at its default(open) position?"

Comment: I have never heard *let* use this way (AmE). Could you find a dictionary definition with such a meaning?

Comment: I think what you are looking for here is that you want to ask the other person whether he wants the door closed or open. If that's the case then you should ask - "Do you want the door open / closed"? / Or you may ask "Should I keep the door open"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the door is currently open, whether or not it would return to the open position by default, you would say, "May I leave the door open?"

If the door is closed or nearly so, then you can say, "May I let the door open?" Basically, substitute "allow" or "permit" in the sentence; "May I allow the door to open?" only makes sense if the door is not already open.

Comment: Agreed.  The only way "let" makes sense is if the door is closed, and you're asking if you can *allow* the door to open.  (Even then, it's a strange word choice.)